# I`m trying to link my sql database with Java/spring but get this error

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am new with Spring and Java. Im trying to get data from sql but get this error. I don`t know if I am doing correctly

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: El número de puerto 1280/syno no es válido.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
SQLServerException.java:234
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1997) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
SQLServerConnection.java:1997
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1291) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
SQLServerConnection.java:1291
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:881) ~[mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar:na]
SQLServerDriver.java:881
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
DriverDataSource.java:121
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
PoolBase.java:364
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
PoolBase.java:206
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
HikariPool.java:476
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
HikariPool.java:561
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
HikariPool.java:115
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
HikariDataSource.java:112
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180


and more.....
```

Just looked for default path to conenct database thats why i use 1280
This is what I have in yml:

```
spring:
    banner:
        location: "banner.txt"

    datasource:
        url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1280/syno


    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        hibernate: 
            ddl-auto: update
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2019Dialect
```

Comment: Please confirm that the sqlServer is running on port 1200 and the database is present.

Comment: Consider rewording the title ‘my sql’ is too similar to ‘MySQL’, and I thought you’d just used the wrong url/dialect/driver 

Comment: My bad, I mean SQL server. I configurated the port but I get null

Comment: Googling that gives the following answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123744

Comment: After configurate, run: netstat -an | find "1433"  and its lsitenning but couldn't fix the error. Do you think the problem is `database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2019Dialect`  ?
Also changed to `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/syno`

Comment: I realized when I: mvn clean install I get an error too (It's frustrating)
`[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\51942\Desktop\prueba3). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. `
This what i have in POM:
`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Can you connect to your SQLServer instance with another client, e.g. DBVisualizer, or the JDBC client in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL driver class as:-

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 0):

use driver class name and the username & password of the database

spring.datasource.driverClassName=

spring.datasource.username=

spring.datasource.password=

and also add this dependency

```
`
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
  </dependency>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try considering setting these properties-

```
spring.jpa.database-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2019Dialect
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/syno      
spring.datasource.username= YOUR_USERNAME
spring.datasource.password= YOUR_PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```